# C# use of < > (not as greater than / less than)

Tags: c#, list, syntax

In C# Sometimes the use of < and > is required

Lists is one such example

List mine = new List();

in this case why are the <> needed when declaring the type?

Variables and arrays do not require this so why are lists different?

Comment: Well... Have you tried using `break;`? :D

Comment: Would you believe [break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)?

Comment: If you structured your code properly, then you wouldn't need to break.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the break keyword.

See:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the big red emergency break button, rather exit the loop gracefully and provide your fellow programmer with a boolean up on top to let him know that there's an additional condition that might end the loop.

```
<?php
$i          = 0;
$stillGoing = true;

while ($i < 5 && $stillGoing) {
    echo $i;

    if ($i == 3) {
        //break out of loop
        $stillGoing = false;
    }
    $i = $i++;
}
```